# updating gridview in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, gridview, broadcastreceiver, fragment

I have a fragment with a gridview which contains list of downloadable items,i need to update gridview downloaded items but i have some difficulties to get gridview in BroadcastReceiver.  bellow is my BroadcastReceiver code:

```
BroadcastReceiver griddownloadReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       //check if the broadcast message is for our Enqueued download
       long referenceId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1);

       GridView gv1=(GridView)getView().findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
       adapter = (GridAdapter) gv1.getAdapter();
       //final GridAdapter adapter = (GridAdapter) ((GridView) getView()).getAdapter();
       adapter.setDownloadFinished(referenceId);

       // Ask the adapter to refresh the ListView
       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

      }
};//end of broadcast reciever
```

what should i put instead of these 2 lines f code?

```
 GridView gv1=(GridView)getView().findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
 adapter = (GridAdapter) gv1.getAdapter();
```

Answer (score 0):

> what should i put instead of these 2 lines f code?

In fragment's [onCreateView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle)) save reference to adapter in private field, then access it in your `griddownloadReceiver` that should be placed in that fragment.

Don't forget about registering it in `onResume` and unregister in `onPause`.

Then ensure that method `setDownloadFinished(referenceId)` works properly.

Comment: i'm newbie to android. how can i save a reference to adapter?

Comment: i did the same coding for activity and listfragment with no problem but i can't understand what is wrong with gridview.

Comment: @user3906385, _reference_ is, in short, just newly created object ;) e.g. `adapter = new GridAdapter(...);`

Comment: @user3906385, first, ensure that `griddownloadReceiver` is invoked, then check if method _setDownloadFinished_ is working correctly - check if data item was really updated (assuming this is purpose of `referenceId` param). If you still have any problems, please update question with method code.